# Setting multiple eventTypes on an AccessibilityServiceInfo

Tags: java, android

In the Android API, I see the [AccessibilityServiceInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html) class has the public field `eventTypes`. I am wondering if this can be set to more than one of the type constants (e.g. `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` and `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED`). And if so, what would the syntax for that be?

The name being a plural would suggest it can be set to multiple values, but I just can not work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it this way:

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
```

See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#register).